# How to optimize converting integers to strings and back and summing them

Tags: python, arrays, string-concatenation

Today I was doing the practice pre-screen test on Code Signal and one of the questions was this.

*Given an array of integers a, return the sum of all a[i] º a[j], where a[i] º a[j] is defined as the concatenation of a[i] and a[j] e.g., if a[0] = 1 and a[i] = 2 then a[i] º a[j] = 12.*

The correct output can be obtained with `sum(int(str(ai) + str(aj) for ai in a for aj in a)` but it is too slow for one of the hidden test cases. Caching `str(ai)` and `str(aj)` does not make it fast enough either. How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Are the inputs only single digits? Please provide more extensive test cases

Comment: Could you include an example input array?

Comment: Can you pls provide *any example at all*. WIth the actual input array and the expected output?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because working code should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Wombatz without code it would closed in a heart beat

Answer (score 2):

If you only have single digits, you could simply multiply by 10:

```
sum(10*i + j  for i in a for j in a)
```

This is about 4 times faster than using strings.

If you can have numbers with an arbitrary number of digits:

```
from math import log10, ceil

l = [10**int(ceil(log10(x+1))) for x in a]
out = sum(n*i+j for i in a for n, j in zip(l, a))
```

This is about 60% faster on 20 items (400 combinations) and 3 times faster on 1000 items (1M combinations).

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to not use strings to build concatenations if you are always given a single digit in your list:

`sum(10*i + j  for i in a for j in a)`

if you could be given any number then you could do as @mozway pointed out and generate a sidelist of the coefficients

```py
from math import log10, ceil

l = [10**int(ceil(log10(x+1))) for x in a]
out = sum(n*i+j for i in a for n, j in zip(l, a))
```

But these solutions are not changing your from O(N^2) to anything better they are just reducing the horrible cost of the system calls in constructing the string and returning it as an integer, which is agreeably a very slow process that should be removed.

You could however truly massively speed this up and do it in a single pass O(N).

**Updated to fix issue with length squared being the wrong multiplier**

```py
a = list(...) # your input
sum = 0
len = len(a) # get the length
# you are going to count each element as the one and the ten digit in list^2 number of occurences.. so just multiply
for i in list:
    sum += (int(i) + (int(i)*10))*len

return sum
```

Answer (score -2):

def concatenatedSum(a):
result = 0

```
for num in a:
    current = num
    while current > 0:
        result += current % 10
        current /= 10

return result
```

#example

a = [1, 2, 3]

print(concatenatedSum(a))